# Javascript issue inside of a Python Module

Tags: javascript, python

I'm trying to have Python run some Javascript, and I am running into a few issues. Namely that when I am trying to inject some text into a textarea of a page, it doesn't seem to work if and only if there is a newline (\n) as part of the variable inserted for the Javascript.

Here's my line:

```
br.runjs("document.getElementById('edit-body').value = '%s'" % (brag))
```

if the variable "brag" has any sort of newline in it at all, the insertion does not work. Any idea how to go around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encode `brag` as JSON and then use that.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to do that? My Javascript is far less good than my Python, I can only do basic things (in order to interact with web pages). Working on picking up more, but still not there.

Comment: `>>> print "var foo = %s" % (json.dumps('bar'),)`
`var foo = "bar"`